# CSS Text wrap on element (not really related to wordwrap or whitespace)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, word-wrap

So here's the gist of it, please bear with me.

I've got a a logo it consists of text and an image (Example: big@company in this example @=logo image). I'm building a wordpress site and want to use the php bloginfo( 'name' ) to automatically fill in the text of this logo, but I have this image that I have to load in between the words.

I come from a print design background and essentially what I'm trying to do is place the image on top of the text and have the text warp around the image. Make sense?

The reason I'm trying to do things this way is to keep it seo friendly, I realize I could just hard code things the way I want and just text indent -9999 the php bloginfo part, but have read recently that google is starting to view this as a spam technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

`big<img src="logo.jpg" style="display:inline"/>company`